# Array values not being changed by method

Tags: javascript

not a js expert so this might be a stupid question but...

Why does the log show that the array has changed? I was expecting the array still to be a [0,0] since the method is invoked after the console.log. Also, if I try to replace the whole array like this:

```
this.my_array = [1,0];
```

the log will still show [0,0], which is something that makes more sense to me. 
What's going on?

```
function Y() {        
  this.my_array = [0,0];            
  this.changeIt = function() {
    this.my_array[0] = 1;
  };
}

var z = new Y;
console.log(z.my_array);
z.changeIt();
```

​

Comment: Please don't ask two separate questions intermingled, it makes it very hard to understand, and it makes it hard for answers to be clear.

Comment: What's interesting is that stepping through the code in Chrome outputs [0,0], but executing it outright outputs [1,0].

Comment: I'm actually getting `[0,0]` when I run this in the commandline (Firebug).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some browsers (Chrome, for instance) `console.log` displays a *live*, interactive display of your array, not a point-in-time snapshot. So if you're looking at the console after this runs, it's been updated because of the change. Chrome also does slightly different things when you use `console.log` interactively in the console panel than when you use it from within a script.

You'll see what you're expecting if you display a string instead:

```
var z = new Y;
console.log(z.my_array.join(", "));
z.changeIt();
```

That shows the point-in-time snapshot you're expecting.

Comment: But then why isn't the console.log display updated in its place if run `z.myarray[0]=2` in the Chrome console?

Comment: nice catch and nice answer, however... +1 now :)

Comment: @chumkiu: Thanks. This is actually something I learned here at SO, but I can't find that question now to link to it...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LyhgW/

Edit: The fact that i'm using `alert` makes this code work. This works around Chrome's live-feature in the console and displays a snapshot instead.

Comment: `alert` and `console.log` are very different things.

Comment: @ Lukas: It does on Chrome. Using [an updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyhgW/1/), I see [1, 0] twice in the console. As chumkiu points out, Firefox doesn't do the "live" thing either, but Chrome does.